# I get an error trying install pytorch 1.7.0

Tags: python, pip

i tried to install pytorch with this command:

`python -m pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

and I got this error message:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.11.0+cpu, 1.11.0+cu113, 1.11.0+cu115, 1.12.0, 1.12.0+cpu, 1.12.0+cu113, 1.12.0+cu116, 1.12.1, 1.12.1+cpu, 1.12.1+cu113, 1.12.1+cu116)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0`

how  do I fix that?

Comment: May be changing the python version fix your issue

Comment: you mean using pip3 or even python3?

Comment: Have you tried to install it with pip? pip3 install torch